An expression for $\int_0^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx$
Is there an expression in terms of $a$ for $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx$?
If $u=\ln(ax)$ we have that $ du = \frac{1}{x}$ and $x = \frac{e^u}{a}$, and the integral is $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^u}{a}\right)^{-u} du$
which looks very similar to the Gaussian integral. Is this a step in the right direction? 

Your integrand can be written as $e^{-(u^2-u\ln a)}$. Now complete the square.

https://i.sstatic.net/xFDjd0ki.png

Solution:
If $u = \ln(ax)$, then $x = \frac{e^u}{a}$. So, for $x \to 0^+$, we have $u \to -\infty$, and if $x \to \infty$, we have $u \to \infty$. Also, $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{a}{ax} = \frac{1}{x}$. Therefore, $xdu = \frac{e^u}{a}du = dx$.
So, $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^u}{a}\right)^{1-u} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(u-1) \ln(a) - u^2 +u} du$$
The last integral was just using exponential and logarithmic properties like:

$a^{u-1} = e^{(u-1)\ln(a)}$
For all real numbers $m$ and $n$ and $a>0$, we have
$$\frac{a^{m}}{a^n} = a^{m-n}$$
For all real numbers $m$ and $n$ and $a>0$, we have
$$(a^{m})^{n} = a ^{mn}$$

Now completing the square we have:
$$I = e^B \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(u - A)^{2}} du$$
where $A = \frac{1+\ln(a)}{2}$ and $B = \left(\frac{\ln(a)-1}{2} \right)^2$
Using $m = u-A$ and $dm = du$, we have the Gaussian integral. That is,
$$I = e^B\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-m^2} dm = \sqrt{\pi} \exp \left({\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a)-1)^2} \right)$$ where $\exp(x) = e^x$.
Therefore, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx = \sqrt{\pi} \exp \left({\frac{1}{4}(\ln(a)-1)^2} \right)$$
Bonus: If $a = e$, we have that $I = \sqrt{\pi}$ because is exactly the Gaussian integral!

The correct transformation is, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx \to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^u}{a}\right)^{1-u} du$$
and not,
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\ln(ax)} dx \to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^u}{a}\right)^{-u} du$$
Since the other answer nicely explains the former correct form , here's how you would do the latter incorrect one,
$$I=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^u}{a}\right)^{-u}\,du$$
$$I=e^{\frac{\ln^2(a)}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e)^{-\left(u-\frac{\ln(a)}{2}\right)^2}\,du$$
Substitute $u-\frac{\ln(a)}{2}=t$
$$I=e^{\frac{\ln^2(a)}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e)^{-t^2}\,dt$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi}$$
$$\boxed{I=e^{\frac{\ln^2(a)}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}}$$
